# Counting the number of multiples of number A that perfectly divides the number B

Tags: algorithms, coding-theory, mathematical-programming

What is the best way of counting the number of multiples of number A that perfectly divides the number B.

This is the sub problem for one of the questions I am solving on codechef.
This is the best I could come up with.

```
int func(int A,int B){
    int res = 0;
    int i = 1;
    while(A * i <= B){
        if(!(B %(A * i))){
            res++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return res;
}
```

However,this is timing out for some of the cases. I am told that this can solved in O(sqrt(n)). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you also provide the url to the original question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by checking whether $A$ divides $B$. If it doesn't, we're done, the answer is $0$. If it does, let $C = \frac{B}{A}$. The numbers you're looking for are all of the form $AM$ where $M$ divides $C$, so all you need is the number of divisors of $C$.

Let $C=p_0^{c_0}...p_n^{c_n}$ be the prime decomposition of $C$. The number of dividers of $C$ is then $\prod\limits_{i}(c_i+1)$, so the problem boils down to the prime decomposition of $C$, which can indeed be done in $O(\sqrt{C})$:

```
residue = C
divider = 2
number_of_prime_dividers = 0
factors = empty array
while((residue >= divider) and (divider <= sqrt(C))
{
    if(divider divides residue)
    {
        number_of_prime_dividers = number_of_prime_dividers +1
        factors[number_of_prime_dividers] = 0
    }
    while( divider divides residue )
    {
        residue = residue / divider
        factors[number_of_prime_dividers] = factors[number_of_prime_dividers] + 1
    }
    divider = divider + 1
}
if(residue != 1)
{
    number_of_prime_dividers = number_of_prime_dividers +1
    factors[number_of_prime_dividers] = 1
}
```

This algorithm works because by construction, every time `divider`divides `residue`, then it means that `divider`is prime (if `divider` is composite then all the factors of `divider` are strictly smaller than `divider` and thus have already been removed from `residue`). Once we reach `sqrt(C)`, if `residue != 1` we know that `residue` is prime, which concludes the decomposition.